# AbstractMethodError after hibernate update

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

After update hibernate (in JBoss 7.2.0) from 4.2.14 to 5.3.7 I have AbstractMethodError exception. It could be some dependency issue but I don't know where should I look for. Anyone could give me some advice on how to solve this problem?

**Error log:**

```
[org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] (task-scheduler-1) Encountered an error executing step stepOne in job MyJob: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:160) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to threat : https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-at-org-hibernate-type-customtype-nullsafeget/780/11

Try to use jasypt-hibernate-5 instead:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt-hibernate5/1.9.3